# How to extract images from pdf using Java (not using pdfbox)

Tags: java, image, pdf, rendering

I've being researching on how to extract images from a big (> 300MB) PDF file. I'm using pdfbox but for some particular reason that I can't figure out, some pages are not correctly extracted.

I'm using the PDFToImage class of pdfbox as base for my code.

So, do you know another library that may help me to do this? I know that iText may be used, but I read that it can't be used for commercial products.

I've installed the packages xpdf and xpdf-utils, and the utility called pdfimages is working perfect. But I need to solve this problem from Java and it should be portable.

Comment: You can port xpdf-utils to Java.

Comment: iText is under GPL unless you purchase a commercial license.

Comment: I will try with versions < 5, I think that the change on the licensing terms were changed for versions >= 5.

Comment: What is wrong with the images that aren't correctly extracted?

Comment: In two particular pages, that are composed from different embedded images, the output for each page is wrong.. is hard to describe..... The different embedded images are letters and the final page has like holes between the letters....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you're talking about two different things here: extracting images from a PDF, and converting PDF pages to images.  `PDFToImage` will output an image for every page, while pdfimages extracts all embedded images (e.g. a text document has 0 images).

Take a look at [`org.apache.pdfbox.tools.ExtractImages`](https://pdfbox.apache.org/docs/2.0.13/javadocs/org/apache/pdfbox/tools/ExtractImages.html) ([source code](https://github.com/apache/pdfbox/blob/ef4b8ef75811124dfc22cc8a852a613b1d5f39e8/tools/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/tools/ExtractImages.java)) to see if it does what you want.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I'm trying to convert a PDF page to an image, not to extract all the embedded images. The thing is that the PDF that I'm using in this particular case has one image per page. Sorry for the misunderstanding. I've also check ExtractImages with no luck.

Comment: I've finally used pdfbox, the thing is that pdfbox will not extract to images correctly PDFs which has fonts that are not recognized, or CMYK colorspace. For PDFs without these problems, the library works ok.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely reason why it is hard working with 300 Mb PDF's is that you run out of memory.  If it works well for smaller PDF's I would have a closer look at why it fails.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [icepdf](http://www.icepdf.org/) or [JPedal](http://www.jpedal.org/) (both pure java)?

Comment: Nop, I did not. Can I use any of those in a commercial Product?

Comment: They both have LGPL and commercial versions. You can use either in a commercial product.

Comment: I've tested Icepdf, the pages are extract ok, but I'm having problems with fonts now :(. I'm using this as a guide: http://wiki.icefaces.org/display/PDF/Converting+PDF+Page+Renderings