# Extracting Images from PDF

Tags: pdfbox

I have used PDFImageWriter class to convert PDF to image file(png). Now i want to crop pictures(images) from the converted image file.I dont know how to do?could any one provide some code for this?

Comment: I am using Java Language and pdfbox-app-1.5.0.jar

Comment: You want the images, so you render it and then want to crop out the parts that were images to begin with?

Answer (score 1):

may be it will work.

```
private BufferedImage cropImage ( BufferedImage src , Rectangle rect ) {
  BufferedImage dest = src.getSubimage ( rect.x , rect.y , rect.width , rect.height ) ;
  return dest ; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to Crop an Image using Java then this may answer your question: [java image crop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3495566/java-image-crop)

If you are trying to extract images from a PDF then this may answer your question: [How to extract images from pdf using Java (not using pdfbox)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4315836/how-to-extract-images-from-pdf-using-java-not-using-pdfbox)